# Preventing Page unload, failure. Ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to mimic a feature found even here on this site. But it doesn't appear to work. I am attempting to do this with jQuery 1.4.4 so far what I have, after crawling through as many examples I could find here and on other forms I came up with.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function()
{
    if(show_unsaved_warning == true)
    {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var exitBeforeSave = confirm('You have unsaved changes');
        if(exitBeforeSave == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Which works to the point of displaying the confirmation dialog, but whether you click ok or cancel, the page still loads/reloads. I need to prevent this similar to the way stack does, so if there is changes made on a form, I can prompt the user to save the changes in case they forgot, or just let them leave. Is there something I am missing in this equation or is it just not possible?

Please note I realize this is a question asked a dozen times over here on stack and on dozens of forums elsewhere. If I could piece something together based on the things I found otherwise I would n't ask. Im coming here with a obvious repeat question cause I am currently stuck.

***edit*** I changed the code a tiny bit to work with the confirmation dialog, however, the problem still pretty much remains, and on firefox I am actually causing an ok/cancel dialog which after ok/cancel is clicked, firefox creates another prompt to leave/stay on its own. How can I avoid that behavior as well?

Comment: `if(show_unsaved_warning == true)` is better written as `if(show_unsaved_warning)`. Similarly `if(exitBeforeSave == false)` is better written as `if(!exitBeforeSave)`. I know it's a minor point, comparing boolean variables with true/false always gets my goat. Also, mixing camelcase with underscores for variables in the same function is the surest way to lose sanity in an untyped language. (was it exitBeforeSave or exit_before_save??? You wouldn't know until runtime).

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using a confirm with onbeforeunload? It does it by default.

Your outdated jQuery version

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    if(show_unsaved_warning == true) {
        return 'You have unsaved changes.';
    }
});
```

jQuery 1.7+

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    if(show_unsaved_warning == true) {
        return 'You have unsaved changes.';
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVc3C/)

Comment: unfortunately until my company gives me the green light on a full rebuild I am stick with jquery 1.4.4 I've tried to bring in a new version standalone and with the use of noconflict and the software breaks the original author put a tangled mess of code together.. anyway the outdated way you illustrate fails me it works but still continues to load the next page or reload as I tried that first before the idea of confirm

Comment: When you hit cancel the next page should not load. You saying it still loads?